# Private entity in a Singleton EJB can not be found with a named query

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, ejb

I have a Singleton EJB that initializes two entities in the beginning:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class PetShopSingleton {

@Inject
private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

private Animal cat;

private Animal dog;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    cat = AnimalRepository.findByType(AnimalType.CAT);

    dog = AnimalRepository.findByType(AnimalType.DOG);
}
}
```

The entities are initialized from a service running a named query:

```
@Stateless
public class AnimalRepository extends BaseRepository {

public Animal findByType(AnimalType type) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("type", type);

    return findOneByNamedQuery("Animal.findByType", params,
            Animal.class);
}
}
```

The findOneByNamedQuery is a method in the abstract BaseRepository class:

```
public <T> T findOneByNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> parameters, Class<T> clazz) {
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName, clazz);

    applyParameters(parameters, typedQuery);

    List<T> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        return results.get(0);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The enumerable class used in the named query looks like this:

```
public enum AnimalType {
    CAT,
    DOG;
}
```

And finally the persistent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMALS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "Animal.findByType",
        query = "select a from Animal a where a.type = :type"
    )
})
public class Animal {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AnimalType type;

    public AnimalType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setTyp(AnimalType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

The one entity (cat) was an older one and was registered in the database, the newer one (dog) has been registered recently. The issue here is that the service called in the init() function to find the two entities with the named query finds only the cat. The dog is returned null although there is an entry in the database with a TYPE column equal with DOG.

Can anyone help me or give me possible reasons why this is happening?

The database is an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the issue, there was a column in the table with a file path for the animal avatar that started with C:/path/to/avatar, I changed it to /path/to/avatar and it worked. Still don't know why this happens but it's fine now :)